# SAXParser does not understand encoding 'EUC-JP'

Tags: c++

sax parser throws exception when I parse following file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='EUC-JP'?>
<note>
  <to>George</to>
  <from>John</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>·ÑÂ³meeting</body>
</note>
```

If I remove first line and  line with Japanese characters then parser works.

```
<note>
  <to>George</to>
  <from>John</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
</note>
```

Any idea how to make it work for other encodings also.

Comment: You typically need a Unix operating system to get that encoding recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing for sure what SAX parser you're using. Does this help?

http://www.lllf.uam.es/~antonio/documentos/xerces/faq-parse.html#faq-20